# How to calculate the output impedance of an oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, impedance, clock, time-constant, calculate

Is it possible to approximately calculate the output impedance of an oscillator if the rise/fall times at a given load capacitance are known, simply by using the formula for the RC time constant T = R * C?

For example:

- CMOS oscillator e.g. [Datasheet of a CMOS Oscillator](https://ele.kyocera.com/assets/products/crystal-device/clock_k_e.pdf)
- tr/tf (10% to 90%): 5ns @ 15pF load
- R = 5ns/15pF = ~333 Ohms

  Actually for 10% to 90% the 5ns needs to be divided by maybe ~2.3 because it's more than one time constant.
- R = 5ns/2.3/15pF = ~145 Ohms

Background: I want to calculate the effect on rise/fall times when adding additional capacitance to the output of a CMOS clock oscillator and for rise/fall time calculation I need the impedance as well.

Is the basic idea right? If not, how is it done?

Comment: So, can you draw exactly the oscillator you have in mind? Because I'm not sure whether you're incorporating an output buffer stage, but even if you weren't, I wouldn't directly link "impedance" to time constants. I put "impedance" in quotation marks, as it's a property of a linear component. Nothing about a CMOS oscillator is linear... so you might want to check how *useful* the impedance measure acutally is; I'd argue you just need to calculate / simulate the whole circuit as active CMOS circuit, not as some complex impedance combined with a load.

Comment: Actually, I meant a prefabricated CMOS oscillator as offered by various manufacturers (I have added a sample data sheet). These are specified for a certain maximum load capacitance, and I wondered how a lower load capacitance would affect the rise and fall times. But as you said, since these are nonlinear components, it's probably impossible to calculate anything useful.

Comment: So, that means you're not at all asking about an oscilator – you're asking for how load capacitance will affect the rise time of a CMOS amplifier! These devices all come with an output stage that decouples the oscillator from the load you attach. It stops mattering that it's an oscillator generating that signal; for all practical aspects, a square clock signal is no different then just a bunch of irregular edges.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial video on how to model a CMOS driver using the device paremeters: [How to model a FET/CMOS Driver using a Datasheet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mnf-VAFbNnQ).